# variable namespace in matlab

Tags: matlab, namespaces, workspace

Recently I found a problem in matlab code when calling `assignin('caller',...)` in a function to make new variables in the caller function, if the variable name is the same name as a matlab function name in the path.

Here is a simple code snippet just to demonstrate the problem.

```
function myfunctest
  sin = 0;   
  subfcn_set; % call subfcn_set to make a new variable
  whos % list variables in current workspace
  sin % raise error because it calls the sin function
end

function subfcn_set
  assignin('caller', 'sin', 'I am sine');
end
```

save the snippet into `myfunctest.m` and run it in matlab

```
>> myfunctest
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes    
  sin       1x9                18  char     

sin =    
I am sine
```

Everything looks good. But if I delete `sin = 0` in `myfunctest` and run it again,

```
>> myfunctest
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes    
  sin       1x9                18  char     
Error using sin
Not enough input arguments.    
Error in myfunctest (line 8)
sin
```

The builtin `sin` function is called even if the the variable `sin` existed as indicated by `whos`. This applies to other matlab function names in the path too.

If we change the variable name from `sin` to some other thing, e.g., `notafunc`, everything looks good regardless the initialization.

```
>> myfunctest
  Name          Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes    
  notafunc      1x13               26  char   
notafunc =    
I am notafunc
```

Comment: All variables that share a name with a function on the Matlab path need an explicit assignment to tell the compiler that you're using the symbol as a variable.  Answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412276/puzzling-error-with-script-run-in-function/26414381#26414381).

Comment: Yes, the answer is at point. That post does not look directly related and I didn't find it by searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not a "problem". From the documentation of `assignin`:

> `assignin(ws, 'var', val)` assigns the value val to the variable `var` in the workspace ws. The `var` input must be the array name only; it cannot contain array indices. If `var` does not exist in the specified workspace, `assignin` creates it.

Since there is a function `sin()` existing in the namespace matlab does not create the variable.

Apart from this I would not recommend this approach since it will confuse other persons using your code. In case you do not know that this line exists, you will not realize what happens. An exception can be made for subfunctions to other functions, in case the subfunctions are defined in the same .m file as the function using the subfunctions. However, even then it should be used sparsely in case the file is large.